# How to iterate ids from dataframe into API to use to make calls with?

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, python-requests, api-design

I have a dataframe that has 'id' column in it among 14 other columns.

```
df = 

id   column2
123  adfa
455  adfadf
```

I need to take each of the ids in the 'id' column and iteratively pass them into an API url, and store the result of the API output, ideally in a list.

The API URL looks like this:

```
r = requests.get(https://URL/v1/orders/{id}, headers = headers)
```

Each of the ids from the above df need to be passed into `{id}` and the result needs to be stored in the list **[]**

I dont how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
["https://URL/v1/orders/{id}".format(id=id) for id in df.id]
```

For OP's edit:

```
for id in df.id:
   r = requests.get("https://URL/v1/orders/{id}".format(id=id), headers = headers) 
   ...
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I made an edit, not sure how I would run your line inside of a response variable 'r'?